# Dynamically load google ad slot via jquery

Tags: jquery, adsense

I need a solution to load an ad slot via jquery .

The ad slot which I am trying to load is :

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "abc1234";
    google_ad_slot = "23445";
    google_ad_width = 300;
    google_ad_height = 250;
    //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

How can I load this ad slot via jquery in the page ?